# tell rpm to use newer version of dependency

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, rpm, tbb

I have an RPM that requires TBB >= 4, however on aws linux I only have tbb 2.x. I have compiled tbb 4.3 from source and places the files in `/usr/include/tbb` & `/usr/include/serial/tbb`.

If I now manually try to install with `rpm -ivh`, the install fails with a message

```
error: Failed dependencies:
        tbb >= 4 is needed by xxx.rpm
```

So how can I tell the install that the new version is available in /usr/include/tbb?

thx Art

Comment: Create an rpm from the source and install it by creating the .spec and using `rpmbuild`

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing an RPM that requires TTB >= 4, then presumably there exists in the same source a necessary version of TBB.  Otherwise, it sounds like you are trying to mix and match RPMs from different sources  in ways that are almost guaranteed to cause problems.

You need to either (a) install a package that contains the necessary dependency information to satisfy TBB version requirement, or (b) you need to install *everything* from source instead of a single dependency.

While you could build a package yourself satisfying (a), the fact that you have an rpm with this requirement suggests that such a package already exists.

Trying to combine the two practices (install from package vs. install from source) is only going to cause sadness and doom.